# Haskell - Lacking of patterns in function

Tags: function, haskell, pattern-matching

I'm trying to add 0s to the beginning of a list. My module is successfully loaded but when I try below function with some parameters  I get `Non-exhaustive patterns in function`. Here's the code, `offset n` is just an integer

```
extraUnicodeList :: Int->[Int] -> [Int]
extraUnicodeList n [] = []
extraUnicodeList n [a] 
  | (n==0)   = [a]
  | otherwise = replicate (offset n) 0 ++ [a]
```

Which case am I still missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've covered the case where there are 0 elements (`[]`) and where there is one element (`[a]`). You're missing all other cases.

To match non-empty lists of any size, you'd use the pattern `x:xs` which will match any non-empty list, bind its first element to `x` and the remaining elements to `xs`.

`[x]` only matches one-element lists and binds their single element to `x`.